# Unable to work with hidden folders in the office365 Graph mail folder API

Tags: email, directory, office365api

I have successfully created some mail folder, and then made it hidden with the following update:

```
patch /users/xxx@xxxx/mailFolders/folderId

{"singleValueExtendedProperties": [{"id":"boolean 0x10f4", "value":"**true**"}]}
```

<sup>(explanations about creating a hidden folder https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659505(v=exchg.150).aspx):</sup>

Then I checked it with *EWSEditor.exe*, which proved the folder was successfully made hidden.
(But the patch call return 404, I think it is some bug of this API, it should return 200 since the update is successful)

After that, if I try to make the folder visible, the update always fails:

```
patch /users/xxx@xxxx/mailFolders/folderId

{"singleValueExtendedProperties": [{"id":"boolean 0x10f4", "value":"**false**"}]}
```

And for this hidden folder, there is no way to list it out or find it out. Trying to delete this hidden folder with the remembered ID fails, too.

So, it seems there are some bugs in the Graph mail folder API:

1. It should be allowed to make a hidden folder visible after a
   previous update to hidden from visible.
2. There should be some API to list the hidden folder.
3. The Delete API should be able to delete the hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

Reset this property to false in EWS editor and save. You will be able to get this folder again with graph api.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now available in Graph Public Beta. You can access hidden mail folders via the /mailFolders API by adding a new query parameter called *includeHiddenFolders*. ​You can read more about the feature @ below links:

About Hidden Folders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-beta#hidden-mail-folders

Get a list of hidden mailFolders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-include-hidden-folders-in-the-signed-in-users-mailbox